# Running Python Script with lynx command in Terminal

Tags: python, emacs, terminal, lynx

I just installed emacs and python on my Mac and I'm trying to learn how to run my Python Scripts through my terminal and I'm getting an error message 
"sh: lynx: command not found". From what I have researched it sounds like i need to install lynx on my mac but I do not know how to get it installed so if that is the issue how do I install lynx on a macbook? I will include screenshots of the issues I'm having. Thanks very much!
[python script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDamC.png)[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/789AB.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should already have Python on your mac. My Macbook Air came with python 2.x on El Capitan OSX. When you open up the Terminal and type in "python" without any quotations does the python interpreter come up? From the look of your image, there is something wrong inside the file you are trying to run with python.

As far as I know, Lynx is a Web Browser, are you trying to do something with Lynx inside that python file? If you happen to have brew on your mac you can try brew install lynx   to install lynx onto the mac.

From the script, I think you are trying to get the source code from the link you are trying to open with lynx. Try this method instead if that is what you are doing.

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

html = urlopen("http://www.careercast.com/jobs-rated/2016-ranking-200-jobs")
with open("lang.txt",'w') as output:
    output.write(html.read())
```

You can use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) to install urllib.request. If you do not have pip, it is very helpful when installing python packages, or you can use easy_install. Run this in the terminal if you already have pip installed. Otherwise follow [this to install it](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/).

```
pip install urllib.request
```

Comment: Yes when I type in python it says Python 3.5.2 and I have brew and installed lynx successfully but still receive the same message- sh: lynx: command not found

Comment: Have you tried running that command you have in the os.system() on the terminal by itself?

Answer (score 0):

You might see the above error if Lynx package is not installed on your server. Follow the below steps to install lynx on your Linux Server

Login to your Linux Server via SSH as root. Run `yum install lynx` to install lynx package